# How can I run my react-native app on the device outside of my home network?

Tags: ios, react-native, device

Right now I can successfully run my react-native app on the device (iPhone/iOS).
However, I have to be connected to my WI-FI for that to work (no need to be plugged in with USB). When I disconnect from my WI-FI the app no longer works on the phone. It doesn't load properly/crashes. Is there a way to run my react-native app on the device outside of my home network/wi-fi?

Comment: @Akza It can be done through TestFlight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are running react-native 0.29.0 or above you can simply change the scheme to "release" and it should build an offline bundle of your app - so you can use it without being on your wifi.

If you are using react-native 0.28.0 or below then you still need to change the scheme to "release", but you also need to change some code in your `AppDelegate.m` file:

Comment out this line:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

And then uncomment this line:

```cpp
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

This puts your app into "Production" mode so you will not be able to access the debug menu.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This worked. For those like me who diidn't know how to change from 'debug' to 'release': Choose "Scheme" from the "Product" menu > "Edit Scheme". Change "Build Configuration" inside of the "Info" and "Run" panel from "debug" to "release". Then re-run your app on the phone.
You can also access the edit scheme window by pressing the shortcut keys "cmd+shift+<"

Comment: Wow, thanks.  This allows us to run Debug builds on a physical device without being attached to the Packager, which is essential for seeing what errors the app is generating while dogfooding it day-to-day.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just build a Profile version of your app (Command + I instead of Command + R) or a long click on the run button and select profile.

It will make an optimized build (kind of the same as a production build) instrumented for the profiler and self-package.

You don't need to use the profiler at all, you can just close "instruments" (which will open automatically at the end of the build process) and run your app.